# Undefined reference when using 2 files

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a problem with pointers. I want to use functions from one file, but there is a problem I can't solve.

Here is main file:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include "ilgas_skaicius.h"
#include "stekas.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
  stackType pile;
  int a = Create(&pile); // problem is over here. Undefined reference.
  return 0;
}
```

And here's header file:

```
#ifndef STEKAS_H_INCLUDED
#define STEKAS_H_INCLUDED

typedef struct LinkElem    stackValue;
typedef struct LinkElem*   stackPointer;
typedef struct StackStruct stackType;

typedef int myType;

struct StackStruct
{
   stackPointer end1;
};

int Create(stackType* stack1);
int Delete (stackType* stack1);
int isFull (stackType* stack1);
int isEmpty (stackType* stack1);
int Push (myType value, stackType* stack1);
int Pop(stackType* stack1, myType* value);

#endif
```

What should I do?

Comment: You need to build both source files, and 'link' them together into an executable using a linker. A build system like cmake or a Makefile can help you do this.

Comment: More precisely, you must create the file stekas.cpp and in that file, you must include stekas.h and implement the definition of the 6 functions related to the stack. After that, you must compile and link all the source files (.cpp or .c) into one executable.